# Discuss the convergence and the uniform convergence of a series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

So the series to be discussed is $\sum (nx)^{-2}$ $\ (x\ne0)$.
And I think I can show that the series is pointwise convergent in its domain by comparison test with $\frac{1}{n^2}$.
But I'm not sure how to show that it's not uniformly convergent(I think).
What I currently know is that Weierstrass M-test cannot be applied. And I feel that I have to use the Cauchy Criterion? But I'm not sure how to write the proof.

Comment: Notice that $\sum (nx)^{-2}=ax^{-2}$, where $a=\sum n^{-2}=\pi^2/6$.

Comment: That's definitely a nice shortcut!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume it were uniformly convergent. Then there exists some positive integer $N$ such that for all $x\ne 0$ we have $\left|\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{N}\dfrac{1}{k^{2}x^{2}}-\displaystyle\sum\dfrac{1}{n^{2}x^{2}}\right|<1$, then $\displaystyle\dfrac{1}{x^{2}}\sum_{k\geq N+1}\dfrac{1}{k^{2}}=\displaystyle\sum_{k\geq N+1}\dfrac{1}{k^{2}x^{2}}<1$, so $0<\displaystyle\sum_{k\geq N+1}\dfrac{1}{k^{2}}<x^{2}$ for all $x\ne 0$. Take $x\downarrow 0$ we get $\displaystyle\sum_{k\geq N+1}\dfrac{1}{k^{2}}=0$, a contradiction.

Comment: Or one can choose $x=\sqrt{\displaystyle\sum_{k\geq N+1}\dfrac{1}{k^{2}}}\ne 0$ to get a contradiction at the end.

Comment: I suppose you could only assert the equality when the sum of 1/k^2 is greater than or equal to 0. So it seems like the final part of the proof is circular.

Comment: I don't quite get it. But $\displaystyle\sum_{k\geq N+1}\dfrac{1}{k^{2}}\geq\dfrac{1}{(N+1)^{2}}>0$, doesn't it?

Comment: The final part is due to this: If $x<\epsilon$ for all $\epsilon>0$, then $x\leq 0$.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my argument. No matter what, we must have $\displaystyle\sum_{k\geq N+1}\dfrac{1}{k^{2}}>0$, this is one point. Another point is that, because we have like, $\displaystyle\sum_{k\geq N+1}\dfrac{1}{k^{2}}<\epsilon$ for all $\epsilon>0$, then we have $\displaystyle\sum_{k\geq N+1}\dfrac{1}{k^{2}}\leq 0$, so this point contradicts with the previous one.

Comment: Okay, actually my argument goes in a different way, actually I have used the Squeeze Theorem for limits: If we have $g(x)<f(x)<h(x)$ and $g(x)\rightarrow 0$ and $h(x)\rightarrow 0$, then $f(x)\rightarrow 0$, but in this case such an $f(x)$ is actually the constant $\displaystyle\sum_{k\geq N+1}\dfrac{1}{k^{2}}$, so this constant goes to the limit (zero), so this constant is actually the limit (zero). And of course, in this case, the so called $g(x)$ is actually the zero all the times.

Comment: Oh yes, with squeeze theorem it makes sense. Thanks for your explanation!